# Hausdorff and surface measure

Tags: real-analysis

I know that Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ coincides with Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^n$. But I'd like to see the proof that also surface measure on manifold $M$ coincides with the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^n$ defined with respect to the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^m$ ($m \ge n$) restricted to $M$. Does anyone know any texts/books where I can find it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know about books, but every point of $M$ has a neighborhood that is $(1+\epsilon)$-bi-Lipschitz equivalent to a piece of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which implies the claim.

Comment: @Normal Human Can you show me how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the area formula and the coarea formula. You can find it in this book [Evans and Gariepy](https://www.crcpress.com/Measure-Theory-and-Fine-Properties-of-Functions/Evans-Gariepy/p/book/9780849371578)